# Optimizing and Ridge Regression in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, data-science

I have implemented Ridge Regression using PySpark. I use it on a dataset which size is approximately 1.7 millions rows and 231 columns. It occupies more or less 1 GB. My implementation is super slow depending on which machine I execute it: on google colab it takes 8 minutes to perform 2000 iterations of gradient descent on a subset of the dataset, on my laptop (intel i7 8th generation U and 8 GB of ram when colab is just 2 cores) it takes 4 minutes to execute 10 iterations on the same subset. Below is shown my implementations, is there a way to speed up the process?

```
class SparkRidgeRegression(object):
""" Base regression model. Models the relationship between a scalar dependent variable y and the independent 
    variables X. 
    Parameters:
    -----------
    n_iterations: float
        The number of training iterations the algorithm will tune the weights for.
    learning_rate: float
        The step length that will be used when updating the weights."""
def __init__(self, n_iterations, learning_rate, reg_factor):
    self.n_iterations = n_iterations
    self.learning_rate = learning_rate
    self.reg_factor = reg_factor

def get_training_errors(self):
    return self.training_errors

def set_training_errors(self, error):
    self.training_errors = error

def squared_error(self, target, prediction):
    return (target - prediction) ** 2

def root_mean_squared_error(self, predictions):
    return np.sqrt(predictions.map(lambda p: self.squared_error(*p)).mean())

def mean_squared_error(self, predictions):
    return predictions.map(lambda p: self.squared_error(p[0], p[1])).mean()

def mean_absolute_error(self, predictions):
    return np.abs(predictions.map(lambda prediction: prediction[1] - prediction[0]).reduce(lambda a, b: a + b))/predictions.count()

def r2(self, predictions):
    mean_ = predictions.rdd.map(lambda t: t[0]).mean()
    sum_squares = predictions.rdd.map(lambda t: (t[0] - mean_)**2).sum()
    residual_sum_squares = predictions.rdd.map(lambda t: self.squared_error(*t)).sum()
    return 1 - (residual_sum_squares / sum_squares)


def get_grad_sum(self, example):
    return (self.weights.dot(DenseVector(example.features)) - example.label) * example.features


def fit(self, observations):
    progressbar = ProgressBar()
    features_number = len(observations.take(1)[0].features)
    self.training_errors = []
    self.weights = np.zeros(features_number)        
    start = datetime.now()
    # Do gradient descent for n_iterations
    for i in progressbar(range(self.n_iterations)):
      # Get the prediction given an example and the current weights
      predictions = observations.map(lambda example: self.predict(example)) # Result [label, prediction]
      # Calculate l2 loss
      regularization = self.reg_factor * self.weights
      self.training_errors.append(self.root_mean_squared_error(predictions))
      # Gradient of l2 loss w.r.t w
      grad_w = observations.map(lambda example: DenseVector(self.get_grad_sum(example))).reduce(lambda x, y: x + y) + regularization
      # Update the weights
      self.weights -= self.learning_rate * grad_w

def predict(self, example):
    return (example.label, self.weights.dot(DenseVector(example.features)))'''
```

My version of spark installed is 3.0 with hadoop 2.7
My pyspark configuration obtained from the code is:

```
[('spark.rdd.compress', 'True'),
 ('spark.app.id', 'local-1602447405987'),
 ('spark.serializer.objectStreamReset', '100'),
 ('spark.master', 'local[*]'),
 ('spark.submit.pyFiles', ''),
 ('spark.executor.id', 'driver'),
 ('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client'),
 ('spark.driver.host', 'DESKTOP-0CA7QUP'),
 ('spark.driver.port', '50297'),
 ('spark.ui.showConsoleProgress', 'true'),
 ('spark.app.name', 'pyspark-shell')]
```

Comment: I think more information about your local Spark configuration would be needed to troubleshoot this. Could be Spark executor memory settings are too low or a number of other things.

Comment: My version of spark installed is 3.0 with hadoop 2.7
in the edit there's the spark configuration